# Learning as a combinatorialist

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

Sorry if this isn't appropriate for stackexchange, but I just have been curious. For a combinatorialist, is more effort spent learning specific tools in combinatorics or learning other areas of math related to combinatorics?

My guess is that this will depend on which area of combinatorics, so if I need to be more specific, we can restrict to algebraic combinatorics (but I'd be interested in general).

Comment: This is pretty vague... we're supposed to measure effort? Assuming it would be the same for all learners? Hopefully a combinatorics person can come along with an awesome answer and resolve this situation.

Comment: I agree it is vague, but I can't think of a better wording right now. "Time" is less vague than "effort," but some tasks are more  difficult than others, and would be weighted more than if we just took time.

Comment: @Dtseng Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is simple. The tools to be learned are determined by the problems under which you are working and which part of solution of them belongs to you and which to the coworking with you specialists in another branches of mathematics.